target="_blank" attribute is stripped out of <area> elements on SPO page
SharePoint Online is stripping the target="_blank" attribute out of my <area> elements when I add them to a page by editing the markup directly. This is the relevant code I am attempting to use:
<img src="/sites/TAW/Images1/Image.png" usemap="#Map">
<map id="Map"> 
    <area shape="rect" coords="10,128,208,168" href="https://example.com" target="_blank" alt="Alternate Text"/> 
</map>

Is there a way I can prevent SharePoint Online from stripping out this attribute, or is it doable via some other mechanism (I know <a> elements added via the Ribbon have a checkbox option to open in a new tab, but that's obviously not useful here...)? A JavaScript solution would be acceptable, although it would be a last resort.

Note: this is not the same issue as target="_blank" not working in a tag SharePoint online. That question is about <a> elements where the attribute is not stripped out, just ignored. In my case, the attribute is stripped out altogether. And adding data-interception="off" doesn't change that.
